# Reversed SQL statement asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, arrays

I opened an asp.net project with this query inside of an `aspx.cs` file:

```
from ev in table1
where ev.FromDate > DateTime.Today && ev.Active
orderby ev.FromDate
select ev;
```

This automatically turned into an array.

I'm a newby to asp.net. It's probably very easy but I can't figure how to add another table (table2) and conditions into this!

You would probably ask for the table structure, it's something like:

**table1**

```
event_id  
FromDate  
toDate  
*item_id* [should be used as foreign key]  
Active
```

**table2**

```
item_id [should be used as foreign key]  
Desc   
Lang   
Active
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for linq query to join two table. Assuming you are having tabel2 property as you are having table1.

```
from ev in table1
join item in table2 on item.item_id equals ev.item_id
where ev.FromDate > DateTime.Today && ev.Active
orderby ev.FromDate
select new {ev = ev, item = item};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply join them and select into anonymous type:

```
from ev in table1
join sv in table2 on ev.item_id equals sv.item_id
where ev.FromDate > DateTime.Today && ev.Active
orderby ev.FromDate
select new 
          {
             ev.event_id, 
             ev.FromDate, 
             ev.toDate, 
             ev.item_id, 
             evActive = ev.Active, 
             sv.Desc, 
             sv.Lang, 
             svActive = sv.Active
          };
```